# using boost.python, how to extend a class's __dir__ function?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a class exported to python, in pure python, I can easily extend the **dir** function by this:

```
 def __dir__(self):
    attr = list(self.__attributesMap().keys())
    return attr + dir(type(self))
```

so I added a dir function to my c++ class, but the question is how to get value of `dir(type(self))` in c++ with boost.python?

Comment: Can you also add the c++ code?

Comment: not posible to add the attributes with c++, this class represent many types, each have different attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible.  We could partially declare the class:

```
struct test {
    void foo() { printf("foo!\n"); }
    void bar() { printf("bar!\n"); }
    void baz() {}
};

// define initial tclass
auto tclass = class_<test>("test")
    .def("foo", &test::foo)
    .def("bar", &test::bar);
```

And then extend the **dir** function:

```
auto cur = tclass();
tclass.def("__dir__",
    make_function(
        [cur] (object) -> object {
            list curdir = (list)object(handle<>(PyObject_Dir(cur.ptr())));
            curdir.append("hello");
            return curdir;
        },
        default_call_policies(),
        boost::mpl::vector<object, object>()));
```

But, doing it this way, using an instance of the object itself, we get an infinite loop because it just rebinds internal pointers.  And if we try to call PyObject_Type and call PyObject_Dir on that, we'll get Boost.Python.class back, as it's the actual type of boost::python expose classes, and it doesn't have the correct objects added to it (as that's done dynamically).

We can see this if we look in python:

```
>>> dir(skunk.test)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instance_size__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'bar', 'foo']

>>> dir(type(skunk.test))
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']
```

The type of the class isn't what we'd like.  So you can't use the class itself (infinite loop) and you can't use the type (not a type like we're used to in Python), what's left?  You might be able to define the class twice and use one to feed the dir of the other, but that seems redundant.  Better to just manually write the dir function to hardcode the other methods on the class.  You have to manually .def() them anyways.

Comment: that's what I'm getting into, alwasy a infinite loop for getting the results of dir function. seems I have to find another way to do this.